# spa with angular and express - cannot load templates

Tags: angularjs, express, single-page-application

I try to create a SPA with angular on a node/express server. Please bear with me, I am confused. View engine is `ejs`. On my `app.js` I have

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes.list);
```

`index.js` contains

```
exports.list = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Home'
  });
};
```

so it can render `index.ejs` that contains

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="app">
    <head>
    <script src="./public/javascripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./public/javascripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

        app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        // configure the routes

        $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
        // route for the home page
            templateUrl: './views/home.ejs',
            controller: 'homeController'
        })

        .when(' /about', {
        // route for the about page
            templateUrl: './views/about.ejs',
            controller: 'aboutController'
        })
     )}

        app.controller('homeController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = 'Welcome to my home page!';
        });

        app.controller('aboutController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = 'Find out more about me.';
        });
    </script>

    <title><%= title %></title>

    <div ng-view></div>
     <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="about">About</a></li>
```

`home.ejs` and `about.ejs` are like

```
<h1>About Page</h1>
<p>{{ message }}</p>
```

1- I cannot load the `angular.min.js` and `angular-route.min.js`. I get `angular is not defined` for the `var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);` line in `index.ejs` file and `Unexpected token <` for `<!DOCTYPE html>` on the same file.

2- `home.ejs` and `about.ejs` dont load

3- I replace with `app.use('/#', routes.list);` on `app.js` and `<a href="#"> <a href="#about">` on the `index.ejs` and I get `error 404`. Why the `#` character on the URL causes problems?

4- Should I also create routes for `about` like `var about = require('./routes/about');` and `app.use('/about', about.list);`? Or is an SPA, so routes are not necessary because they will cause page loads?

Sorry for the big question. 
Thanks in advance

UPDATE
on the `index.ejs` file I changed the `app` to `sp` , so no conflicts occur, but the same problems remain.

UPDATE 2
the whole `app.js` is

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('static-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes.list);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

app.listen(4800);
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Make sure to close your `<script>` tag. The tag after the `aboutController` is missing the `/`. See if that helps to load angular. Once you have angular loading correctly, you can have ngRoute load html files rather and ejs. Ejs will only be compiled if you utilize the `res.render` in your express routes. Show your app.js or server.js file please.

Comment: @Alexander Staroselsky In my original code `<script>` is closed, I made a typo here, while copy/paste. I also created html instead of ejs files and tried to render with `ngRoute` , still nothing. Check OP for the `app.js`

Comment: Public is the root of your website. If you look at your app.js file, you will see that you have a path to your public (I want to assume you are working on a new Express app, please post your Express app.js to validate). The public is the root of yourwebsite.com, so to access your javascripts, it will be yourwebsite.com/javascripts. You also can not point directly to your views, you have to render them. This is because they are not in the public folder! see http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html for more info.

Comment: @BrianGerhards You are right, I make a mistake during editing . So I 
1- transfer the `home.html` and `about.html` to the public folder
2- add this `app.use(express.static('public'));` to the `app.js`
3- add this to `index.ejs` , so javacript will be load `<script src="http://localhost:4800/javascripts/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://localhost:4800/javascripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>`
4- add this to `index.ejs` so it can find the `html` files `templateUrl: 'http://localhost:4800/home.html'` and `templateUrl: 'http://localhost:4800/about.html'`
Thanks for your time mate!